# Best way to Switch fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How can we perfectly switch fragments without recreating. Im using below code to switch b/w two fragments. In first fragment i have Implemented feed posts by using a http request in *onViewCreated()* of fragments.And i have a second fragment with some other options.But when i switch back to first fragment from second.. The httpRequest executives again and duplicates
Feed items.But when i switch to the second fragment from first its not happening. 
I use it like

> FragmentUtils.changeFragment(fragHome,R.id.mobile_container,
>   true,(AppCompatActivity)getActivity());

```
public static void changeFragment(Fragment frag,int v, boolean saveInBackstack,AppCompatActivity a) {
        String backStateName = ((Object) frag).getClass().getName();

        try {
            FragmentManager manager = a.getSupportFragmentManager();

            boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

            if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) { 

                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();



                transaction.replace(v, frag, backStateName);

                if (saveInBackstack) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: addToBackTack " + backStateName);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Change Fragment: NO addToBackTack");
                }

                transaction.commit();
            } else {
                // custom effect if fragment is already instanciated
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException exception) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to commit fragment, could be activity as been killed in background. " + exception.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save your HTTP response as a member variable and only perform your HTTP request in onViewCreated if that is null'

```
private String httpResponse;

public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (httpResponse == null) {

        // make HTTP request here
    }
}
```